# Number of xLabel is greater than the length of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I used Morris.js to build the following chart:
http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output

The xLabel have problems when I reduce the length down to 2 as:

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

xLabel show as `2006-03 2006-05 2006-07 2006-09 2006-11 2007-01`

I want xLabel to show only the years like `2006 2007`.
I searched a lot but didn't found any solutions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `parseTime` parameter to false in your Morris configuration:

```
parseTime: false
```

Reference: [Morris Line & Area Charts](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)

> **parseTime**: Set to false to skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating them as an equally-spaced series.